# Get selected date from calendarextender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a textbox extended with the calendar extender in ASP.NET Ajax. If I get the selected date of the calendar, the variable is null, and the text of the textbox always defaults to the value I specified (Default) for when the page loads.

How can I get the selected date when I change it? I need this for the button click event handler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The calendar extender has a selectedDate() property on the client-side API, and a dateSelectionChanged event if you need immediate notification; you can get the selected date via:

```
var date = $find("<%= cal1").get_selectedDate();
```

which should be not null; I looked in the JS and it is setting it when clicking on the day.

HTH.

Comment: Is there a way to get this via C#?

Comment: CalendarExtender.SelectedDate, though I don't know if that refreshes based on what was last selected on the server.  However, on the server, the textbox should have the date value.

Comment: What part didn't work, the server-side selecteddate property?